# email alerts are not working in sharpeont site

Tags: 2007

email alerts are not working in my sharepoint site. all the code is working fine.alert is activated, but no mails are being sent to the users.i checked emails in the spam also,but no use. my code is in the following link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266367/access-denied-when-trying-to-update-an-alert-for-a-user.
i checked all smtp configuration,sharepoint outgoin-emial configuration settigns.all are fine, i couldnt get where its going wrong. please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

This is a great visual on troubleshooting email alerts:
http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

Answer (score 1):

We had a very similar issue recently. It turned out to be nothing to do with SharePoint at all: the network guys had moved the load balancer for the mail servers to a new switch or something but they had not checked that all the existing servers could reach it.

Can your SharePoint server send any email at all? If not go see the network guys. Or the email guys, it could be that the SP server isn't allowed to route mail or some thing.

Comment: i am able to send mails from a functionality in  the site.

Comment: the problem is that alert mails are not sent to the users

Comment: Have you checked that all the Timer Job Definitions and stuff are running OK in Central Admin?

Comment: I checked the timer job definition and stuff all are running active

Comment: Turn on logging for Email and Workflows in Central Admin and then check the server event viewer for errors.